# Howto call external program and get it's output from another program

Tags: c++, qt, ipc

Howto do this in c++:

Suppose that program `A` is a command line tool with some inputs (for example file paths and a number), according to it's inputs, it may get some other parameters during runtime. (`if(condithin) cin<<something`) I'd like to call `A` from another program `B` and want to see complete output of `A` during it's running. `A`'s inputs must be entered (if necessary). `B` is a gui tool written with Qt and `A` must be shown in a plain text area and it's inputs must be shown in same place (like a console client).

I just don't know where to start. Reading something about IPC didn't help. I know it's possible because I see Dolphin's console window and python interpreter in Eric IDE...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use Qt, using [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html) is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

use [QProcess::execute](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#execute) method to start running A. you can form the argument list from B to pass to A. Use [QProcess::readAllStandardOutput ()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) to read the output of the process and display in B.